# В чем отличие в объединении селекторов в CSS

Tags: html, css

Я пытаюсь разобраться в чем разница между выполнением трех разных типов селекторов. Т.е. как они будут выполнены и для каких из них будет применен бекграйуд:

Два сопряженных и один через запятую:

> .uiIcon .itemIcon, .itemIcon {
>    background: black;
>   }

Просто три в ряд через пробел:

> .uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon {
>    background: black;
>   }

Все три класса сопряженные:

> .uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon {
>    background: black;
>   }

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t0jwe1ca/

Comment: @soledar10 Ответ бы сделал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это всё написано в любом туториале по CSS на первой странице.

```
.uiIcon .itemIcon, .itemIcon { background: black; }
```

запятая - это перечисление. не имеет смысла, т.к. 
`.uiIcon .itemIcon` это подмножество `.itemIcon`.
Применится ко всем элементам с классом itemIcon

```css
.uiIcon .itemIcon, .itemIcon { background: black; }
```

```html
<div class="itemIcon">1</div>
<br/>
<div class="uiIcon itemIcon">1</div>
```

```
.uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon { background: black; }
```

.itemIcon вложенный в .itemIcon который вложен в .uiIcon

```css
.uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon { background: black; }
```

```html
<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">Этот белый
    <div class="itemIcon">Этот Чёрный</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon { background: black; }
```

Элемент с двумя классами сразу - uiIcon и itemIcon

```css
.uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon { background: black; }
```

```html
<div class="uiIcon itemIcon">
Этот Чёрный
</div>  

<div class="uiIcon">Этот белый
    <div class="itemIcon">Этот белый</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1** `.itemIcon`:

применяется для всех элементов с классом `.itemIcon`

```css
.itemIcon {
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">.itemIcon</div>
</div>

<div class="itemIcon">.itemIcon</div>

<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">
    <div class="itemIcon">.itemIcon</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="uiIcon itemIcon itemIcon">
  .itemIcon
</div>
```

**2.** `.uiIcon .itemIcon` :

`.uiIcon` родитель для `.itemIcon`

```css
.uiIcon .itemIcon{
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">.uiIcon .itemIcon</div>
</div>
<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">.uiIcon .itemIcon</div>
  <div class="itemIcon">
    <div class="itemIcon">.uiIcon .itemIcon</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**3.** `.uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon` :

`.uiIcon` родитель для `.itemIcon`, который в свою очередь является родителем для `.itemIcon`

```css
.uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">
    <div class="itemIcon">.uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="uiIcon">
  <div class="itemIcon">
    <div class="itemIcon">
      <div class="itemIcon">.uiIcon .itemIcon .itemIcon</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**4.** `.uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon` :

классы заданные для одного элемента

```css
.uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon {
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="uiIcon itemIcon itemIcon">
  .uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon
</div>
<p class="uiIcon itemIcon itemIcon">
  .uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon
</p>
<h2 class="uiIcon itemIcon itemIcon">
  .uiIcon.itemIcon.itemIcon
</h2>
```

Приоритет стилей определется его весом - [Хабр - Взвешиваем селекторы CSS](https://habr.com/post/137588/)